# Need to replace a part of a value in Sql Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, replace

My table name is SOFTSKILL. One of Columns is MakeID. The values in the column are,

```
000277755
000278143
000277738
000277051
```

i need to change 000 into 100, like

```
100277755
100278143
100277738
100277051
```

Anybody please help me how to do this..

Comment: Are these example values and you need a generic method to do the replacement or are the 4 values you supply the only ones required. If you need a generic method is it do you simply need to replace the first character with a 1 every time?

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE SOFTSKILL
SET MakeId = STUFF(MakeId,1,1,'1')
WHERE MakeId LIKE '000%'
```